# IBAction connected to IF statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, annotations, ibaction

I have 2 different buttons that trigger a different set of annotations in a single mapview. I have action methods that fade out the buttons at which point an annotation should appear, but I cannot figure out how to say in the annotation method "if this action is activated, then load annotations from this class." So here is my current code

```
- (void)queryForAllPostsNearLocation:(CLLocation *)currentLocation withNearbyDistance:(CLLocationAccuracy)nearbyDistance {
if (????? IBAction 1 is activated ?????) {
    NSString *button1 = @"Today";
}
if (????? IBAction 2 is activated ?????) {
    NSString *button1 = @"Tomorrow";
}
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:button1];
```

I hope that I am conveying my problem appropriately and someone can help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "an IBAction is activated"?

Comment: Where does the third button1 variable come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, and by "activated" you mean "has been touched"/"has been selected", you're doing things backwards.  Instead of checking whether the button has been selected within your `queryForAllPostsNearLocation` method, have your button trigger the necessary query.  In the following example, I've made `button1` and `button2` correspond to the UIButtons and I've replaced `NSString *button1` with `NSString *buttonText` just to make things a bit clearer.

```
- (IBAction)buttonSelected:(id)sender {
    NSString *buttonText;
    if (sender == button1)
        buttonText = @"Today";
    else
        buttonText = @"Tomorrow";

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:buttonText];
}
```

Edit:  In order to complete your desired query in this case, you can either (1) store currentLocation and nearbyDistance as class variables then access them within `buttonSelected` in order to complete the query there or (2) you can fetch the `currentLocation` and `nearbyDistance` values within `buttonSelected` then call a method like

```
// Modified to now include the button's text as an argument
-(void)queryForAllPostsNearLocation:(CLLocation *)currentLocation withNearbyDistance:(CLLocationAccuracy)nearbyDistance withButtonText(NSString*)buttonText
```

from within `buttonSelected`, then perform the query from there.

Comment: that makes perfect sense except how do I include that PFQuery within the queryForAllPostsNearLocation?

Comment: I appreciate all your help but have one last question.. Everything is working except I think I run into a problem since the (void)queryForAllPosts loads immediately and doesn't do anything once the buttonSelected is touched down.. So what I am asking is if there is a way for the queryForAllPosts to update and reload each time buttonSelected is touched down?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  At this point, where are you calling queryForAllPosts?  You should call the method (modified as I've done above) within the buttonSelected method.

Comment: When I include it in the buttonSelected it gives me an error stating "Use of Undeclared identifier 'queryForAllPostsNearLocation'"

Comment: If you private message me with your code, I can help you fix it.